# How to write nlog layout renderer to access individual elements of an array element passed in log method object[] args

Tags: c#, nlog

How to do I access/log elements of the args object array in the Nlog layout when the LogDebug method with following signature is used and an Exception object is passed as a value of this parameterized args array.

public static void LogDebug(this ILogger logger, string message, params object[] args);

Layout l = "${longdate}|${level}|${logger}|${message|....}

Comment: The easy/best solution is creating extension-method that has Exception-object as input-parameter. Ex. `public static void LogDebug(this ILogger logger, Exception ex, string message, params object[] args);`

Comment: But you can access [LogEventInfo.Parameters](https://nlog-project.org/documentation/v4.5.0/html/P_NLog_LogEventInfo_Parameters.htm) when writing you own: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-write-a-custom-layout-renderer